# Multiline text in Excel cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm trying to write multiline text to excel cells.

```
cell.setCellValue("line1 \n line2");
```

But when I open the document, I see only one line until I double-click it for editing, then it becomes two-lined. Why is it so? Thanks

Comment: I am completely agree with you I got same behavior with my date value cell and its format

Comment: @jaychapani have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to set the row height to accomodate two lines of text.

```
row.setHeightInPoints((2*sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));
```

You need to set the `wrap text = true` to get the new line.
Try this :
Here wb is the `Workbook`.

```
 CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
 cs.setWrapText(true);
 cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Comment: This doesn't help. My problem is not about row height. The text is written in one line until I double-click the cell.

Comment: @vikiiii I guess wraptext would work according to column width. What if I forcefully need text in the next line??

Comment: @vikiiii I have the same issue but the solution doesn't work for me. If I press "Format" in excel before double-clicking the cell, "word wrap" property is not checked. After double-click text is split in 2 line and "word wrap" is check.
Where is the magic?

Comment: @Dennis - you have to set the row height and wrap text style as above but also adjust the width of that column after you've added the data, e.g., "sheet.autoSizeColumn(2)".  This works for me with the 3.15 JAR

Comment: You must set cell value before you set cell style.<br/> Not work:<br/> cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);<br/> cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("abc\r\ndef"));<br/> Work:</br> cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("abc\r\ndef"));<br/> cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

Answer (score 2):

I found that you have to now include a third step after you follow the accepted answer to this question.  You have to auto-size the column after you've added all of your data.

Assuming you're concerned about column 2,

`sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);`

See [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/NewLinesInCells.java) example from Apache for context.  It works for me with Java 8, poi-3.15.jar, and Excel for Mac.

Comment: I would not recommend using autoSizeColumn it's a slow operation , instead a function can be created that sets size to a particular column. I would highly recommend creating a wrapper class called for example ExcelBuilder and create function that you would often use to modify your excels

Comment: @ArtjomProzorov can you write up something as another answer?  I can't test this right now

Comment: This indeed slow like hell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

cell.setCellValue("line1 \n\r line2");