# Apache POI: new line without wrap

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to write multiline text in one cell, but without wrapping them.

Expectation:

[image: two lines - expectation]

I start with simple:

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("First text line. \r\nNew line.");
```

[image: first]

It not works, but I found ([1](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewLinesInCells), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428274/multiline-text-in-excel-cells/11428334#11428334), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601520/n-doesnt-work-on-excel-cell), [4](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-poi-write-multiline-text)) that I need `setWrapText(true)` to show new lines and set height of row:

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("First text line. \r\nNew line.");
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
row.setHeightInPoints(2 * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints());
```

[image: second]

It works (visible new lines, height of two lines), but text is wrapped.

If I `setWrapText(false)`, I'm back to where I started (new lines isn't visible):

[image: third]

How to show new lines, but don't wrap text?

<sub>Apache POI 5.2.4, Libre Office.</sub>

Comment: If you open Excel and right-click on an empty cell, then choose `format cell`, you will see that `Wrap text` under `Alignment` is not selected. If you copy a string with a new line in it and follow the same steps again, you will see that `Wrap text` has been automatically checked. To me, this means that a new line will not work without `Wrap text` being true.

Comment: In MS Excel you're right. Even if I paste multiline text and uncheck `Wrap text` it hides new lines. But in LibreOffice Calc it works differently. If I paste multiline text, it's not wrapped. I can `Format Cells` -> `Wrap text` check and uncheck and new lines are preserved. You can see it on first screen in question (I made it manually in Libre).  That's why I assumed it's possible in Apache POI. Maybe the library does just what it's possible in MS Excel.

Comment: Good observations! I am not sure why the difference exists. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache POI creates the Office Open XML file format and this file format is not able to store what your first screen shot shows - one cell having multiple text rows where the text nevertheless overflows the right cell border.

Libreoffice uses Open Document file format which is able to store what your first screen shot shows.

Create what your first screen shot shows using Libreoffice Calc. Then save that as `*.xlsx` (Libreoffice calls this Excel 2007-365-Format). Now close and reopen the file. You will see the overflow the right cell border is gone.

Now again create what your first screen shot shows using Libreoffice Calc. Then save that as `*.ods` (ODF-Format). Now close and reopen the file. You will get it exactly as got saved.

So the problem is with Office Open XML file format `*.xlsx` versus Open Document file format  `*.ods`. And Apache POI is to create Office Open XML file format only.

Comment: Note to the last sentence: Apache POI can create `*xlsx` (`XSSFWorkbook` ), but it can also create `*.xls` (`HSSFWorkbook`). But of course generally you're right (it can't create `*.ods`, so it's impossible what I wanted).